# Antwort auf "Wie ist Ihre gewünschte Einsatzdauer?"

Tags: sentence-structure, single-word-request

Ich bewerbe mich für eine Praktikumsstelle und soll diese Frage beantworten. Ich habe ein dreimonatigen Praktikum und ein Masterarbeit zu absolvieren. Also ich bin verfügbar für 9 Monate aber ich möchte hier erzählen, dass 3 Monate Praktikum(ab Januar) oder 6 Monate Masterarbeit(ab April) oder 9 Monate für beide zusammen gewünscht. Natürlich beide Zusammen ist am meisten gewünscht. Wie kann man das schön und gut wie ein Muttersprachler beschreiben?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folgendes könnte die Frage ausreichend beantworten:

"Meine gewünschte Einsatzdauer beträgt insgesamt 9 Monate. Diese setzen sich aus 3 Monaten für das Praktikum und 6 Monaten Zeit für die Masterarbeit zusammen."

Wunsch bei (möglicherweise) getrennten Zeiträumen:
"Meine gewünschte Einsatzdauer beträgt insgesamt 9 Monate. Zunächst möchte ich für 3 Monate ein Praktikum bei Ihnen durchführen (*). Direkt daran anschließend würde ich gerne die 6-monatige Masterarbeit in Ihrem Hause absolvieren."

(*) hier eventuell: "..., um die Firma und die Abläufe besser kennen zulernen." einfügen.

Somit kann sich der Personaler (engl. "HR") aussuchen, was ihm/ihr besser zusagt.

Comment: But is this sentence also describe that only 3 months doing praktikum or 6 months master thesis is also okay?

Comment: Well, they ask for your "wish". Your wish is to stay for 9 months. Just write that.
To add a "backup wish" is another story... see above.